# php ; using fgetcsv with SplFileObject::fseek ; line read issue

Tags: php, fgetcsv, fseek, splfileobject

When reading a specific line in a csv file, I tried to use `SplFileObject::fseek` with `fgetcsv`.

To read line 2 (for example), I do a `fseek(1)` and read with `fgetcsv`, which gives line 2.

When I do a `fseek(0)` and read with `fgetcsv`, I have line 0.

So there is a issue to read line 1 this way. (I know I can read 2 lines in a row but don't think it is nice).

I found this issue reported in 2008 with PHP version 5.2.6 : [SplFileObject: fgetcsv after seek returns wrong line](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/08bdv92byg/46569-new-splfileobject-fgetcsv-after-seek-returns-wrong-line).

I'm using PHP verion 5.4.19.

Has anyone some information on this?
Is this intended?

Comment: Better to link to the PHP bug site: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46569

Comment: They haven't closed the bug report, so I don't think it's intended. They just haven't gotten around to fixing it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old bug but it's still opened on bugs.php 
So here is a snippet I want to share to achieve the same (which at least work in my case)

```
function readBigCsv($path, $skip=1)
{
    $file = new \SplFileObject($path, 'r');
    $file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    $file->seek($skip);

    while (!$file->eof()){
        yield $file->current();
        $file->next();
    }

}
```